# How do I store an uploaded file in the correct directory using Laravel Livewire 3?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I have this page that uploads the user's avatar to the the app. I'm using Livewire 3, so it should be simple.

```
// validation
$user->avatar = $this->photo->store('avatars');
$user->save();
```

Now, this works, but instead of storing the file in `/storage/app/public/avatar` it uploads it to `/storage/app/avatar` so I can't see the files in the browser. Field in the database has the hash and file extension, so it's working, and if I go directly to the directory, of course they're there.

This won't work:

```
<img src="/storage/{{ Auth::user()->avatar }}">
```

neither

```
<img src="{{ asset('/storage/') . Auth::user()->avatar }}">
```

But if I manually move the `/avatar` directory inside `/storage/app/public`, it works.

This must be a configuration issue for sure, but I don't know what. I don't find it in the Laravel documentation or Livewire's, it should be working like magic, but it's not.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `config/filesystems.php`, there is an array with `default` key that indicate your default disk, and a `disks` key, that contains your available disks and their information as an array, (you can also add yours). Since you said your files were uploaded at `/storage/app/avatar`, I guess you are using defualt disk, `local`. you can change `default` disk to `public` which store files to `storage_path('app/public')` or change your code to

```php
$user->avatar = $this->photo->store(path: 'avatars', 'public');
```

Read more
https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/uploads#storing-uploaded-files
https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/filesystem#the-local-driver